# Remove the hash table element does not release the memory

Tags: java, android, hashtable

I am trying to keep the frames received from Camera into hash table for later use in Android application.

```
1. Receive Frame ( data of type byte [] )
2. I just have a counter variable increased each frame received. 
3. Using counter variable i keep in the Hash Table along with 'data'.
4. If i reach the counter > 100, then i start deleting from the beginning.
```

So, together it is kind of maintaining fixed size of hash table.

I tried with below code.

```
Callback -> Received 'data'
counter++;
myHashTable.put(counter, data.clone());

if ( counter > 100) {
     byte [] b = (byte[]) myHashTable.get(counter-100);
     //use 'b' for some other purpose.
     myHashTable.remove(counter-100);

    }
```

**My Observation**

I checked Memory usage of application, it keeps on growing, and after some time receiving OOM exception. What Am i doing wrong ? I checked in the Android studio memory usage monitoring.

Below is the error:

```
01-04 22:54:55.232 7966-7999/sample.app.com E/art: Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 460812 byte allocation with 216448 free bytes and 211KB until OOM"
```

Comment: What are you using `b` for when you say "use `b` for some other purpose"? If something is keeping that reference to `b`, it can't be garbage collected.

Comment: Note that `byte[] b = (byte[]) myHashTable.remove(counter - 100);` would be easier than getting and removing separately.

Comment: Why not simply reset your counter when you get to 100 so you overwrite older content ?

Comment: @Tanis.7x   Thanks for your points. Will check the same.

Comment: @Andy Turner Thanks. Will check this.

Comment: @AndyTurner , it started working with your fix. But, how this approach is different than the one i posted in Question?

Comment: @Whoami it's removing `b` before you use it "for some other purpose", not after. As to why that's different depends on what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

i think simple solution to that is you are not setting counter to 0 when it reaches > 100 
add inside if(){ counter=0} thats it i guess since it an infinite loop 
try to debug it by adding print statement and lookup your console.